# Solution to a underdetermined system in terms of adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm reading a book on functional analysis, and at the begining of a page I have the following theorem: 
[image]

Afterwards, the author talks about undertermined system of equations with the following text:
[image]

What I don't get in the text is why the $x=T^*(TT^*)^{-1}b$ from $Tx=TT^*y$ minimizes $|Tx-b|$? Also, why can we be sure that $(TT^*)^{-1}$ exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from what I could understand, there are infinite solutions to $Tx=b$, i.e. $T^*Tx=T^*b$.

An $x_*=\text{argmin}_{Tx=b} |x| $ is equivalent to an $y_*$ which minimizes $|x_0-y|$ with $y\in \ker(T)$, i.e. $x_*=x_0-y_*$.

By the minimization proposition for Hilbert Spaces, a few pages before, we have $|x_0-y_*|$ is minimimum iff $x_0-y_*\in (\ker (T))^\perp$

The operator $T$, in finite dimensions, is represented by a matrix with linearly independent rows. Then $TT^*$ is the Gram Matrix which in this case is invertible. (I'm not so sure if this is 'generalisable')